# Can you specify a deployment target with Octopus Deploy API

Tags: devops, teamcity, octopus-deploy

I am trying to use Octopus Deploy Deployment API and i ran into a problem where the deployment runs on all deployment targets, is there a way to specify the deployment target i would like to run the deployment on.

```
curl --location --request POST '$(octopus-url)/api/$(SpaceId)/deployments' \
--header 'X-Octopus-ApiKey: API-KEY' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "ReleaseId": "Releases-ID",
    "EnvironmentId": "Environments-ID",
}'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the machines you want to deploy to using the `SpecificMachineIds` property. It's an array type, and you need to know the machine ids, not the names of the machines:

```bash
curl --location --request POST '$(octopus-url)/api/$(SpaceId)/deployments' \
--header 'X-Octopus-ApiKey: API-KEY' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "ReleaseId": "Releases-ID",
    "EnvironmentId": "Environments-ID",
    "SpecificMachineIds": ["Machines-1", "Machines-2"],
}'
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: `[Optional] A comma-separated list of machine
                             names to target in the deployed environment. If
                             not specified all machines in the environment
                             will be considered.`

Comment: I assume that helpt text is from the CLI and not calling the API directly. The OP was for a direct HTTP request to the API which expects IDs, not names afaik.